# trying to stick image in the grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I build a grid with 1fr 1fr and each one of them is 50%.
in the left size i want to get HEADERS and P's and in the right side
i want to set IMG. i want the image will be stick to screen in the right
while the left size will act like a page.
how can i do that?

this is my code for the right box with the image:

```
***css***
.grid > box2 {

background-color: blue;
border: 2.5px solid black;
padding: 0.5em; 
image-width: 50%;
 float: right;
}
.grid > box2 img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you mean from your description. Perhaps you could try a mock-up of your situation in code pen?
What what I think you mean, you could try setting the image on the right as a background image and then fixing it in place.

```
.rightSideStyles {
background-image: url("./path/to/your/img.png");
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```